# How to find if Embedded Cassandra is already running or not in version 3.0.3

Tags: embedded-cassandra

In `Embedded-Cassandra` `3.0.3`, what is the way to find if Cassandra is already running or now.

https://nosan.github.io/embedded-cassandra/#introducing

In version `2.x`, there was a API `getState == State.STARTED`. What is the equivalent in version `3.0.3`. I can't find it in the docs or examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing in Embedded Cassandra 3.0.3.
If Cassandra.start() method has successfully finished it means that Cassandra is running and ready to accept connections.

Comment: I have created a new issue. Could you please check that such functionality could be added so that the same instance could be used by multiple parallel running tests. https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra/issues/135